# WordNet / jwnl - iterating through all nouns

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet, jwnl

is it possible to iterate through all the nouns or verbs inside the WordNet dictionary using JWNL and - e.g. - print them out? I want to create a big list with all nouns, but didn't find anything about iterating the dictionary using JWNL.

Thanks

Max

Comment: Have you had any success with this?